# Trouble understanding intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble understanding the intersection of subspaces.

My book says $U\cap W = \{\mathbf{v}:\mathbf{v}\in U$ and $\mathbf{v}\in W\}$. But it doesn't have good examples.

Let $U$ be the subspace generated by $(1,2)$ and $W$ the subspace generated by $(2,3)$. What does "generated" mean in this context? Does it mean $U = u_1+2u_2$ and $W=2w_1+3w_3$? I am very confused by the terminology in my book.

Lastly, is $U\cap W = \{\mathbf{0}\}$?

Comment: Are $U$ and $V$ subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Adam Rubinson Hold on, I forgot some details. I don't quite know what they mean so I overlooked them.

Comment: I think you probably meant "subsets"?  In which case your formulas don't mean anything.
Otherwise, you should post the definition of "space" and "subspace".

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last question, are you assuming that U and V are 1-D vector spaces here? If so, if $U = span(\{ (1,2 )\} )$ and $V = span( \{ (2,3) \} )$, then $U \cap V = \{ (0,0) \}$, which qualifies as a vector space.

A more visual example: think of two distinct planes in $\mathbb R^3$ intersecting the origin. These correspond to two 2-D vector spaces, and their intersection is a line, which is a 1-D vector space.

Comment: I had to make some edits because I overlooked the word "generated". I don't know what it means. They are in $\mathbb{R^2}$. I also don't know how to find the span of something. That was going to be my next question. I know that a basis spans a vector space but a span isn't necessarily a basis.

Comment: Ah I see. In the math world, we talk about a space generated by a set $S$ as the "smallest" space $U$ that contains your set.  Here, smallest would mean that if some vector space $V$ has all the points in $S$, it also happens to contain $U$ as a vector subspace.  If $A = \{ (1,2) , (0,3) \}$, then $span(A)$ is the vector space generated by $A$, is any point in $\mathbb R^2$ which I can express as $ r_1(1,2) + r_2(0,3)$ with $r_1$ and $r_2$ real numbers.  It's a common exercise for students learning linear algebra to prove that $span(A)$ is in fact the vector space generated by $A$.